# HTML/Javascript How can I link a button to another button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Help. I want to link a button to another button. I have two .html files.

index.html and output.html

Here is the case, 
in my index.html I have a form and a button in the form. Just an example

```
    <div id="additionForm">
    <form class="form-addition">
    Assume that this form requests for two values and will add that values.
    <button type="submit"">ADD</button> 
    </form> </div>
```

Then assume that when the ADD (submit) button is clicked, it will be directed to output.html which will display the result.

In the output.html, how can I create I button which if I press that button, It will "call" the form in the index.html?

For example, 
I pressed the button on the output.html 
A form from index.html must be called.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say the form in output.html will "call" the form in index.html what exactly do you mean? Do you mean it will submit the earlier form with the previously gathered values? Or do you mean it will enable you to navigate back to the previous page?

Comment: The form from the index.html will appear in the output.html, Then I shall input another values and if I press submit, it will calculate again. The button was clicked from the output.html page

Comment: Why don't you just put then both forms there? It's a bit strange what you want. Can you maybe give further information what "calulate" means and what should happen with the data or so?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<div id="outputForm">
<form class="form-output">
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='index.html'">Click Me!</button>
</form> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div id="outputForm">
  <form class="form-output">
   <button type="button" onclick="call()">Click Me!</button>
   </form> </div>

  <script>
  function call()
  {
      window.location.href ='index.html'
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.